# websql insert slow

Tags: html, cordova, web-sql

I have about 300 records I need to insert into a websql.  I started out by writing 300 separate tx.executeSql insert statements without parameters.

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO `beerlist` VALUES ('1', '21st Amendment', 'Back in Black IPA', '83', 'IPA', 'A');");
```

On Chrome, this takes 2ms.  Running thru phonegap on Android, this takes about 43,438 ms.  So I switched to iterating over some JSON & using prepare statement. Like so:

```
var beerList = {"beers":[{"beerid":"1","brewery":"21st Amendment","beername":"Back in Black IPA","bascore":"83","beertype":"IPA","beertable":"A"}}

$.each(beerList.beers, function(i, object) {
                    var insert = 'INSERT INTO beerlist VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
                    tx.executeSql(insert, [object.beerid, object.brewery, object.beername, object.bascore, object.beertype, object.beertable], Beer.successInsert, Beer.failureInsert);
                });
```

I read where prepare should be faster, but I'm seeing the same performance on Chrome & actually a slightly worse performance thru Phonegap on Android at 53,559 ms.  I can't believe it's going to take ~50 seconds to insert 300 records.  Any thoughts?

Comment: websql is known for being slow and actually is deprecated. The alternative is IndexedDB (which is quite horrible too...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using multiple transactions?  Its probably not your inserts that are slow, its the transactions.  Multiple executes wrapped in a single transaction are considerably faster

```
db.transaction( function(tx){
    for (var i = 0; i < args; i++)
    {
        tx.executeSql(sqlStmnt, args[i]); //args is nested [[1,2],[1,3]]
    }
},
dfd.reject,
dfd.resolve);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [success handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#sqlstatementcallback) of executeSql was invoked with a transaction object. The trick is reuse that transaction and send parallel requests. Basically you use single transaction, but controlled execution of multiple, but few, async requests. You should able to store it under few ms.

In your example, it is uncontrolled. All of your 300 requests are queued before executing none of them. That may even crash the browser.

An example implementation can be found at putObjects method in https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/raw/master/js/ydn/db/core/req/websql.js